# Replace paranthesis with "_" leaving all the contents as it is

Tags: python, regex

I have a verilog file in which some inputs and ouputs are named as 133GAT(123).For example

```
nand2 g679(.a(n752), .b(n750), .O(1355GAT(558) ));
```

Here, I have to only replace `1355GAT(558)` with `1355GAT_588` and not for `.a(n752)` There are multiple such instance.

I tried with python3.

```
re.sub(r'GAT*\((\w+)\)',r'_\1',"nand2 g679(.a(n752), .b(n750), .O(1355GAT(558) ) ")
```

It is giving output as

```
'nand2 g679(.a(n752), .b(n750), .O(1355_558 ) '
```

My expectation is to get the output as

```
'nand2 g679(.a(n752), .b(n750), .O(1355GAT_558 ) '
```

Comment: So `1355GAT(558)` gets replaced because there's only one value in the surrounding parenthesis group `.O(1355GAT(558) )`, and `.a(n752)` doesn't get replaced because it's a sibling of `.b` and `.O` in the surrounding group `g679`?

Comment: `1355GAT(558)` these are port names and only these have to be replaced as it interferes with module instantiation.

Comment: OK, regex works off of rules though, so I'm trying to determine how (textually) these values differ.

Comment: These port names have numbers followed by **GAT** followed by (numbers)

Comment: Does [`(\d+GAT)\((\d+)\)` replace with `\1_\2`](https://regex101.com/r/87QNM4/1) work for you?

Comment: Why do you have `*` after `GAT` in your regexp? That matches `GA`, `GAT`, `GATT`, `GATTT`, etc.

Comment: I got ``'nand2 g679(.a(n752), .b(n750), .O(_1355GAT ) '

Comment: Did you change your replacement to what I wrote, seems you still have `_\1` as replacement - it should be `\1_\2`?

Comment: @user3548672 Works for me: https://ideone.com/3cN1xJ

Comment: Yes it worked for me. Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Why your code is not giving you expected results

Your regex `GAT*\((\w+)\)` matches `GA`, `GAT`, `GATT`, etc., and while it matches `GAT` in your string, you're effectively replacing it with your substitution since you never capture it and include it again in the substitution.

---

### Regex 1

This works and gives you the option to check for digits before `GAT`.

[See this regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/87QNM4/1/)

```
# regex
(\d+GAT)\((\d+)\)

# replacement
\1_\2
```

### Code 1

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##FcuxCsIwFIXhPU9x6ZJ7MQSbEqsUBydHF8eAtLRoB9Nwk0J9@thsH//hhF/6LL7Jef6GhRPwJESEK1S@96OB96m9oO7Rt9aQAj0UHYseWDfW3m9PtPZMQNRVgvcjS3TjYe/ksIgcSbGVYdJxHZAVS1e/nJEqkgg8@4Qb5fwH)

```
import re

s = "nand2 g679(.a(n752), .b(n750), .O(1355GAT(558) ));"
r = r'(\d+GAT)\((\d+)\)'
x = re.sub(r,r'\1_\2',s)
print(x)
```

---

### Regex 2

This works too, but uses one capture group rather than two.

[See this regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/87QNM4/3)

```
# regex
(?<=\dGAT)\((\d+)\)

# replacement
_\1
```

### Code 2

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##FcuxCsIwEIDhPU9xdMkdhmBbYhUt4uTo4hiQlpbawTRcItSnj832w8fvf/G9uDql@eMXjsCjEAFaKFznhgqmQ3NC3aFrTEUKdJ9rn@uBZW3M/fZEY44EROdC8DayxOultcMmZBHtsCNLUqyZRh2@PbJi@bKlVIGE59lFXCmlPw)

```
import re

s = "nand2 g679(.a(n752), .b(n750), .O(1355GAT(558) ));"
r = r'(?<=\dGAT)\((\d+)\)'
x = re.sub(r,r'_\1',s)
print(x)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the nice clarification. Can you please explain me what this **?<=**  from the second code ?  Is it particular to Python or is it also applicable to general regex rules as in say 'sed' ?